# Which of the following does not form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

u = $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$
v = $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Which of the following does not form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ when taken together with u & v?

(a) = $\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\\2\end{bmatrix}$
(b) = $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$
(c) = $\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}$
(d) = $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$

My reasoning is that it would be C because when put in rref it does not end up with all ones as the diagonal, but I got that through trial and error (ie RREFing all 4). Is that how you are supposed to do this problem?

Comment: $$(c)=u+2v...........$$

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm sorry, but I don't understand

Comment: If you add $u$ and $2v$ you get the vector $(c)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct to select (c).

Note that a basis must contain *linearly independent* vectors. This means that you should only be able to get the $0$ vector by adding $0$ times each vector together.

However, if we call the vector from (c) $w$, then $u+2v-w=0$, and so the vectors are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0):

The vector of the item (c) is a linear combination of $u$ and $v$. Indeed,
$$u+2v=(1,0,1)+2(0,1,1)=(1,2,3). $$
Then the vectors $u,v$ and $(1,2,3)$ are linearly dependent,therefore, they can not form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 0):

In general I'ld do as you suggested, but in our special case one may notice that
$$\begin{array}{cc|c}
1&0&a\\
0&1&b\\
1&1&c\end{array}$$
has a solution iff $a+b=c$.